# Error in my code: should return a bool, but returned <class 'NoneType'>

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am working on a program and the question asks:

> The first two ints are a row and column, and the third and fourth ints
>   are another row and column. The last parameter is a symbol board.
>   Return True if the path from the first row and column cell to the
>   second row and column cell, including those two cells, is not
>   completely empty, and return False otherwise. You may assume that the
>   rows and columns given will form a horizontal or vertical path, not a
>   diagonal path.

My code looks like this

```
MIN_SHIP_SIZE = 1
MAX_SHIP_SIZE = 10
MAX_BOARD_SIZE = 10
UNKNOWN = '-'
EMPTY = '.'
HIT = 'X'
MISS = 'M'

def is_occupied(row1, col1, row2, col2, symbol_board):

    if row1 == row2: # Checks the condition if true
        if col1 > col2: # Checks to see if column1 is greater than column 2
            return coordinates_notempty(row1, col2, col1, symbol_board) 
        else: 
            return coordinates_notempty(row1, col1, col2, symbol_board)  
    elif col1 == col2: 
        if row1 > row2: 
            return coordinates_notempty(col1, row2, row1, symbol_board) 
        else:  
            return coordinates_notempty(col1, row1, row2, symbol_board)
```

`coordinates_notempty` is a helper function that looks like this:

```
def coordinates_notempty(c, c2, c3, symbol_board):
    for i in range(c2, c3):
        if symbol_board[c][i] == EMPTY:
            return False
    return True
```

When I run the code in IDLE I get an error that says should return a bool, but returned `<class 'NoneType'>`, but I do not understand why.

After I fixed the syntax error, I still receive the should return bool, but returned  error. It was suggested to add an else statement and when I did

```
def is_occupied(row1, col1, row2, col2, symbol_board):

    if row1 == row2: 
        if col1 > col2: 
            return coordinates_notempty(row1, col2, col1, symbol_board) 
        else: 
            return coordinates_notempty(row1, col1, col2, symbol_board) 
    elif col1 == col2: 
        if row1 > row2: 
            return coordinates_notempty(col1, row2, row1, symbol_board) 
        else:  
            return coordinates_notempty(col1, row1, row2, symbol_board)
    else:
        return True
```

I received an error saying TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple

Comment: In Python, true and false are denoted by `True` and `False`. They must be capitalized.

Comment: ^ I would expect a `NameError` on this basis. Please provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I dont see how i could be more pacific

Comment: When quoting an error message, include at least the last two lines given the line number and text where the error occured.

Answer (score 1):

Setting aside the issue with `true` and `false` that others have found, your `is_occupied` accounts for two possibilities: `row1 == row2` or `col1 == col2`.  If neither is true, then your procedure ends without a return value, and you get `None`.

One final thing.  Your `coordinates_notempty` is going to have an issue as you are checking if a particular element is equal to `EMPTY`, but you never define what `EMPTY` is.

Comment: How exactly would i fix that?

Comment: Without knowing what your symbol board looks like, or what requirements there are for the path, it's hard to say.  You are assuming that there is a straight vertical (columns are the same) or horizontal (rows are the same) line from one point to the other.  The error you're getting suggests that assumption is false.  Basically, you need to answer the question: what if your two points don't fall on a horizontal or vertical line?  Is there only ever one path between the two points?

Answer (score -1):

Try `True` rather than `true` and similarly for `False`?

Comment: Although necessary to fix the program, this doesn't address the OP's immediate problem.